# CMake backward compatibility from 2.8.10 to 2.8.6

Tags: cmake

I've got CMake version 2.8.10 installed on openSuse 12.3. unfortunately the code I worked with is compatible only with CMake 2.8.6. SO, I am wondering If there is any backward compatibility from cmake 2.8.10 to 2.8.6.

Comment: If your legacy code is specifying a [`cmake_minimum_required`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:cmake_minimum_required) or [`cmake_policy`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:cmake_policy) that should take care of any breaking changes. Anything in particular that gives you trouble?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I check if any cmake_minimum_required mentioned. but the point is that I want to use a higher version, and I could not compile the code with the higher version. I let you know if I get any new issue.

Comment: The idea is that if there's a `cmake_minimum_required` specified, any higher versions will behave the same as the specified version. Sort of like a simulated downgrade. In practice this does not always work, so it would be interesting to know the exact error you are experiencing.

Comment: there is the error: $ cmake ..

...
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: CTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS is enabled, but the RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE global property is not defined.

Comment: Hopefully my answer helps you out... Please clarify the text of your question to state "2.8.6" rather than "2.6.8"... (I'm assuming 2.8.6 was the intention.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the following error message:

```
CTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS is enabled, but the
RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE global property is not defined.
Did you forget to include(CTest) in the toplevel
CMakeLists.txt ?
```

...then the solution to the problem is to add one of:

```
include(CTest)
```

or

```
include(CTestUseLaunchers)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt file.

If you need your CMakeLists.txt file to be processed by either 2.8.6 or 2.8.10, you should use the include(CTest) line. CTestUseLaunchers was split out into its own file, but not until CMake version 2.8.10...